# How do I populate manager dropdownlist based on value of employee dropdownlist?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, active-directory

Right now, I am trying to come up with 2 `DropDownList`s, one employee `DropDownList`and the other, manager `DropDownList`.

First, I am not familiar with how Active Directory works but having done some research, I did find something like the code below which as I understand, represents Manager definition:

```
   Dim deEmployee As New DirectoryEntry("LDAP://CN=John Employee,OU=Sales,DC=Corp,DC=com")

   deEmployee.[Property]("manager") = "CN=Peter Manager,OU=Sales,DC=Corp,DC=com"
   deEmployee.CommitChanges()
```

Since there are several manageers, I can hard code the name as done above = `CN=Peter Manager`.

What group represents manager in Active Directory that I can use instead of `CN=Peter Manager`?

The bigger issue for me though is if I select employee from the first `DropDownList`, how does it populate the second `DropDownList`with the manager of that employee?

From what I undersand, department is the attribute that relates employee to manager but how do I use this in code?

In normal cascading dropdownlist, I can select employee and list the department the employee belongs to in the first dropdownlist and in the second dropdownlist, I can select manager where department = theDepartmentListed in first dropdownlist.

That's querying the database but in my case, we are querying the Active Directory.

Can someone please show how to link the relationship between employee in first `DropDownList`and manager in the second `DropDownList` based on department?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in group for managers in AD, the only way you would be able to query them straight out of a group or OU is if your organisation has added one.

There is no automatic linking of employees to managers, so you would have to query the department and select the correct user as the manager.

You will need to write a query that gets all users in a department except for the selected user, something like this should work:

```
Imports System.DirectoryServices

...

Protected Sub EmployeeChanged(sender as object, e as EventArgs) Handles ddlEmployees.SelectedIndexChanged

    Dim selectedUser as new DirectoryEntry(ddlEmployees.SelectedValue) 'assuming your Value on the empoyees dropdown is the LDAP object path
    Dim domainRoot as new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=corp,DC=com")
    Dim searcher as new DirectorySearcher()
    searcher.SearchRoot = domainRoot 
    searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(department=" & selectedUser.Properties("department").Value & "))"

    Dim results as SearchResultCollection = searcher.FindAll()

    For Each result as SearchResult in results

        Dim de as DirectoryEntry = result.GetDirectoryEntry()

        If de IsNot Nothing Then

            If Not de.Properties("samaccountname").Value.ToString().ToLower() = selectedUser.Properties("samaccountname").Value.ToString().ToLower() Then

                ddlManagers.Items.Add(de.Properties("displayName").Value.ToString(), de.Properties("distinguishedName").Value.ToString())

            End If

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

For more information on writing LDAP queries: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: thank you very much. I ran into the following error: `overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' accepts this number of arguments`

 on the following line: `ddlManagers.Items.Add(de.Properties("displayName").Value.ToString(), de.Properties("distinguishedName").Value.ToString())`. I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: That's weird... Try changing it to `Dim newItem as new ListItem(de.Properties("displayName").Value.ToString(), de.Properties("distinguishedName").Value.ToString())
ddlManagers.Items.Add(newItem)`

Comment: Thanks @Sean. Now, I am getting this:

`Value of type 'System.DirectoryServices.SearchResult' cannot be converted to 'System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry'.`

on this line:

`Dim de As DirectoryEntry = CType(result, DirectoryEntry)`

Comment: I replaced result with Sender like:

`Dim de As DirectoryEntry = CType(Sender, DirectoryEntry)`

I don't know if that's the solution but the error disappeared.

Comment: No that's not the solution, that's a mistake on my part, I've edited the answer to reflect =]

Comment: Oh man, this thing is killing me. I tried selecting an option from the employee dropdown and got an `Unspecified error` on this:

`Line 456:        searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(department=" & selectedUser.Properties("department").Value.ToString() & ")(!distinguishedName=" & selectedUser.Properties("distinguishedName").Value.ToString() & "))" 'this filter says we want an object that is a user, that is in the specified department and that it isn't the currently selected user`

I made some adjustments to the brackets after initial error but that didn't help.

Comment: Ok let's change the LDAP query to `"(&(objectClass=user)(department=" & selectedUser.Properties("department").Value & "))"` then manually remove the item later. I'll update the answer

Comment: same error:

`searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(department=" & selectedUser.Properties("department").Value & "))"
`

Comment: Ok, so let's try moving the department property out into a separate variable to see if that's the issue: `Dim selectedDepartment As String = CType(selectedUser.Properties("department").Value, String) searcher.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(department=" & selectedDepartment & "))"`

Comment: Right so there's something wrong with the user variable. What's the value of `ddlEmployees.SelectedValue`?